# How often is the patents-public-data:patents dataset on Google Big Query updated?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to query the patents-public-data:patents dataset. This dataset includes information on U.S. patent classifications according to the CPC guidelines.

There are a couple "publications" tables within the patent dataset. Each of them (except for one) has an assigned date, e.g. 201710 or 201809. I wonder what these dates signify. Which "publications" table is the most up to date? And how often is it updated?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a vendor support question. Contact Google support directly for support regarding their specific services. SO cannot speak on their behalf, and they are the only ones who both know about that schedule and can speak publicly about their timelines.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned, SO is not the appropriate channel for this question; however, if you check the dataset information within [the GCP Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google_patents_public_datasets/google-patents-public-data?filter=solution-type:dataset&q=google%20patents%20public%20datasets&id=2877ec09-debc-41bd-a2d7-df1fd089e4d0) this dataset is updated quarterly. It looks like the table named "publications" is the most up to date one and the tables "publications_201710", "publications_201802", "publications_201809" and "publications_201903" contain the publications until the date indicated within their name.

You can find additional information regarding this dataset in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/google-patents-public-datasets-connecting-public-paid-and-private-patent-data). In addition, in [the BigQuery public datasets documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/#contact_us) you can see  the alias to contact the team that manages the BigQuery public dataset program.